# Gulp run task with success, but nothing happen and no output files

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, concatenation, gulp-minify

After reinstalling node js gulp not working properly, but it worked excellent before. I tried a lot of ways and read a lot of issues on github and forums, but nothing... Tried delete globally installed packages and local installed. Reinstall node js, update node js, install glob@4.2.2 ... etc

Here my gulpfile:

```
        gulp.task('js', function() {
        return gulp.src([               
            'app/js/lightgallery.min.js',
            'app/js/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js',
            'app/js/common.js',
            'app/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'
            ])
        .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js-output'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
        });

        gulp.task('css', function() {
        return gulp.src([
            'app/css/header.css',
            'app/css/bootstrap.css'
            ])
        .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))  
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
        .pipe(cleancss( {level: { 1: { specialComments: 0 } } })) // Opt., comment out when debugging
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css-output'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
        });
```

Here package.json :

```
   {
    "name": "somename",
    "version": "4.0.0",
    "description": "somedescr",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "someone",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
      "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
      "gulp": "^3.9.1",
      "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
      "gulp-clean-css": "^3.10.0",
      "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
      "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
      "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
      "gulp-rsync": "0.0.8",
      "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
      "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
      "gulp-util": "^3.0.8"
    }
  }
```

What i must to do to make it work? Or maybe is any alternative way simply concat & minify js, css, sass on local computer in one click?

Answer (score 0):

I found alternative way to compress js and css using PHP scripts and run it on local server. Found very useful libraries written in PHP:

- Minify JS <strike>(https://github.com/mrclay/jsmin-php)</strike> (https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify/) (12-13% less effective then 'gulp-uglify')
- Minify CSS (https://github.com/tubalmartin/YUI-CSS-compressor-PHP-port) (3-5% more effective then 'gulp-cleancss', maybe due to not existing output from 'gulp-autoprefixer')

And wrote simple master script to use them and make output. Maybe for someone this information can be helpful...

Comment: https://github.com/mrclay/jsmin-php makes errors in js, the better solution for js is https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify/